# Converting Dates Format into the Time Format

Tags: excel, vba

I have two dates in cell `"A1" (Start Date)` and `"B1" (End Date)`. I change the date to get the real figures between the dates using `SUMIFS` formula.

There is `Date` Column in the Sheet with `Time`.

So what i want is that whenever the `"A1" (Start Date)` changes its time should always be initial like `00:00:00` and when i change the date for `"B1" (End Date)` it should always be like `23:59:59` is there any way to achieve this using VBA.

Your help will be appreciated.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B1")) Is Nothing Then
    
    With Range("A1")
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With

    With Range("B1")
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With

    
    End If
```

Comment: A1 should be correct by default since when you add a date to a cell it's in integer (00:00:00). But the B1, you could just add (+) 0.9999999 to the date and it should be 23:59:59

Comment: You mean Start date is by default start from 00:00:00 and when date will be changed every time i have to add to the date (+) 0.9999999. @Andreas I have been looking for a VBA solution if you can provide your help will be really apprecaited. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need to do that. I think you can just enter the dates "normally" (without a time component) and make a small change in your `SUMIFS` formula. The change would depend on the nature of your data, and the `SUMIFS` formula itself.

Comment: Can you please share the change in the formula `=SUMIFS(D:D,E:E,"<>Pending for Payment",B:B,H2,C:C,">="&$I$1,C:C,"<="&$J$1)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric time 23:59:59 is not equal to 0.9999999, it is 0.999988425925926

But use native date/time handling for this and avoid smart numbers:

```
Range("A1").Value = DateValue(Range("A1").Value)
Range("B1").Value = DateValue(Range("B1").Value) + TimeSerial(23, 59, 59)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work, if i understood your question correct.

It will make sure A1 is integer and make B1 integer then add 0.99999.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B1")) Is Nothing Then
    
    Range("A1").value = cint(range("A1").value)
    Range("B1").value = cint(range("B1").value) + 0.99999999

End if
```

Just make sure the cells is set up to display as date and time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But Error on this line `Overflow`  `Range("N10").Value = CInt(Range("N10").Value) + 0.99999999` @Andreas

Comment: I don't know what the value of N10 is or why you have written Overflow in the syntax

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to bother with the time portion of the dates or go throught the mechanics of trying to change it.

You just need to properly construct your `SUMIFS` formula.

- Range to sum: `sumRange`
- Dates in your table: `myDates`

When you enter a date in `A1` or `B1`, it will be entered as if it were at the beginning of the day.

If your dates in `myDates` are just dates, you can use the formula:

```
=SUMIFS(sumRange,myDates,">=" & startDate,myDates,"<=" & endDate)
```

However, if your dates in `myDates` also include a time, then you can modify the formula slightly:

```
=SUMIFS(sumRange,myDates,">=" & startDate,myDates,"<" & endDate+1)
```

*And you can use the 2nd formula in either instance*

***Edit: I just noticed you posting your formula as a comment***

I assume you have entered JUST the date (no time) in `I1` and `J1`

Your formula as posted will work **UNLESS** `C:C` includes times with the dates.  If it does include times with the dates, then try:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,E:E,"<>Pending for Payment",B:B,H2,C:C,">="&$I$1,C:C,"<"&$J$1+1)
```

By adding `1` to the date, we move it to the start of the day after; so we change the `<=` to just `<` and encompass the full range of dates you desire.

Comment: Thank you very much. but it will add the Next date.

Comment: @Valiant No, it will not.  If you are seeing that in your results, you are doing something wrong. Either not entering pure dates for start/end, or maybe you didn't change the comparison operator as shown.

Comment: Oh i didn't noticed that could be the mistake.